# How to retrieve deleted Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there any method or plugins available to retrieve deleted Jenkins job?

I have mistakenly deleted one job from Jenkins. So please give a suggestion to undo the delete.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In fact you have just to use this url to reactivate your deleted job :
`http://[url_of_jenkins]/jobConfigHistory/?filter=deleted`

You just need to have this plugin installed beforehand: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin

Answer (score 12):

It is not possible unless you somehow restore files from your master operating system. In future you can use plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin. This plugin saves configuration files for deleted jobs (but not build history).

Answer (score 7):

Job configs are stored on disk under [`$JENKINS_HOME/jobs`](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins), so if you have a backup of that directory, then you can restore the job.

Otherwise, there's no "recycle bin" for deleted jobs in Jenkins.

In future, if you want to remove a rarely-used job from Jenkins, but there's a small chance that you might want to use it in the future, you can archive the job using the [Shelve Project plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Shelve+Project+Plugin).

Comment: You can also manually archive any job folder under ${JENKINS_HOME}/ and store it some place else with possibility to unpack and replace to restore previous state of the job / build logs etc.

Comment: But if the project gets deleted the logs are also gone from the machine in the folder $JENKINS_HOME/jobs. Let me know how that can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Download Plugin Job Config History

Download steps:- Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugin -> Available -> JobConfigHistory
Download and install

After Installation step:-
Jenkins -> Job Config History -> Show deleted jobs only 
and restore the jobs

Peace...